# Convert String[] array to RedisKey[] array

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Trying to use

```
KeyDelete(RedisKey[] keys, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

I have array of string[] ,
I am not seeing any examples out there when I search for converting these data types. I am not even sure how to create a new RedisKey.

Tried

```
RedisKey redisKey = new RedisKey("d");
```

above does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: There is an implicit conversion defined between `RedisKey` and `string`. If you want a key with the value of "d", just make a direct assignment, `RedisKey redisKey = "d"` https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysValues.md

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisKey.cs) `RedisKey` has an implicit conversion from `string`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a key from a String
/// </summary>
public static implicit operator RedisKey(string key)
{
    if (key == null) return default(RedisKey);
    return new RedisKey(null, key);
}
```

So you can create one by

```
RedisKey key = "hello";
```

or

```
var key = (RedisKey)"hello";
```

---

To convert an `IEnumerable<string>` to `RedisKey[]`, you can do:

```
var keys = strings.Select(key => (RedisKey)key).ToArray();
```